# python itertools product repeat to big

Tags: python, probability, product, python-itertools

I'm trying to make a python script to calculate some win/loss chances. 
to do this i'm trying to get all possible combinations off wins and losses (K is the number of wins needed to win the game):

```
for combination in itertools.product(['W','L'], repeat=(K*2)-1):
    if ((combination.count('L') < K) and (combination.count('W') == K)):  
        #calculate the chance of this situation happening
```

for some reason this works fine, until the repeat becomes to big (for instance if K=25)
Can someone give me some pointers on how to solve this?

Comment: The answer lies in the maths and not the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it fails when the repeat becomes large.  The loop

```
for combination in itertools.product(['W','L'], repeat=(K*2)-1):
```

iterates through `2**(K*2-1)` elements, which becomes prohibitively large very quickly.  For example, when K=3, the loop executes 32 times, but when K=25 it executes 562949953421312 times.

You should not exhaustively try to enumerate all possible combination.  A little bit of mathematics can help you: see [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Here is how to use the Binomial Distribution to solve your problem:  If chance to win a single game is *p*, then the chance to lose is *1-p*.  You want to know what is the probability of winning *k* out of *n* games.  It is:

```
(n choose k) * p**k (1 - p)**(n - k)
```

Here `(n choose k)` is the number of combinations that have exactly *k* wins.

Comment: I got this to work but i'm a little confused by the math.
How would i go about doing the same thing if the chance on winning is dependent on the result of the previous? (the chance to win increases if the previous result was also a win)

Comment: That's a more difficult problem. You may need to ask on math.stackexchange.com . The distribution will depend on  what the dependence is precisely, and it may not have a closed-form solution (meaning, a formula).

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you a clue:

```
>>> for K in range(1,11):
...     n = 0
...     for combination in itertools.product(['W','L'], repeat=(K*2)-1):
...         n+=1
...     print (K,n),
... 
(1, 2) (2, 8) (3, 32) (4, 128) (5, 512) (6, 2048) (7, 8192) (8, 32768) (9, 131072) (10, 524288)
>>>
```

So you are going to have to wait a ***long*** time for a result at K=25. maybe it is time to work out your probability rather than simply calculating it!